# prototype for "...." does not match any in class "..."

Tags: c++

I started to pick up some c++ programming and i am learning the concept of classes and objects. So I looked on the web for some exercises I can practice on. I have read that it is good practice to have the main, header and constructor file separated and not into one long file.

I'm trying to break the following code into three separate files :

```
// Exercises: Classes
// Exercise 3


// Exercises: Classes
// Exercise 3


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student{

public:
char *name;
int mark1;int mark2;

Student(char* na, int ma1,int ma2){
name=na;mark1=ma1;mark2=ma2;
}



int calc_media(){return (mark1+mark2)/2;}

    void disp(){
    cout << "Student:" << name << " \n media:"<< calc_media() <<"\n";
    }

};

int main(){

    char* nam;int m1,m2;

    cout << "Enter name:";
    cin>> nam;
    cout << "Enter marks of two subjects:";
    cin>> m1;
    cin>> m2;
    Student student1(nam,m1,m2);
    student1.disp();

    return 0;
}
```

into the following files:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "student_example.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int marc1,marc2;
   char nam;

   cout<<"Please enter the name of the student:  ";
   cin>>nam;
   cout<<"Please enter the two grades of the student"<<"\n grade one:";
   cin>>marc1;
   cout<<"Grade two";
   cin>>marc2;

   student_Example student1;
   student1.disp();

   return 0;
}
```

header file (student_Example.h)

```
#ifndef STUDENT_EXAMPLE_H
#define STUDENT_EXAMPLE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class student_Example
{
    public:
        char name;
        int mark1, mark2;

        int calc_media(){
           return (mark1+mark2/2);
           }

void disp(){
           std::cout<< " The student named: "<< name<< "\n has an average score equal to: " << calc_media()<<"\n";
        }
};
```

And constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "student_Example.h"

student_Example::student_Example(char nam, int marc1, int marc2)
{
    name=nam;
    mark1=marc1;
    mark2=maec2;

}
```

Im getting the error

```
"error: prototype for **'student_Example::student_Example(char, int, int)' does not match any class 'student_Example'**
```

Any advice what may be going on here? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: When you took class `student_Example` into its own file you didn't take over `Student(char* na, int ma1,int ma2)` with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header file with `class student_Example` doesn't promise a constructor. (And seems to be missing and `#endif`)

```
#ifndef STUDENT_EXAMPLE_H
#define STUDENT_EXAMPLE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class student_Example
{
    public:
        student_Example(char nam, int marc1, int marc2); //<-- as pointed out in the error
        char name;
        int mark1, mark2;

        int calc_media(){
           return (mark1+mark2/2);
        }

       void disp(){
           std::cout<< " The student named: "<< name<< "\n has an average score equal to: " << calc_media()<<"\n";
        }



};
#endif  //<-- this too
```

While we are there we can use an [member initialiser list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) in the constructor

```
student_Example::student_Example(char nam, int marc1, int marc2) :
    name(nam),
    mark1(marc1),
    mark2(marc2) //assume maerc2 was a typo
{    
}
```

---

Edit:
Note that `student_Example(char nam, int marc1, int marc2)` is a declaration that you will define a constructor taking a `char` and two `int`s., which you have done in your cpp file.

You can make an object like this

```
student_Example example('n', 1, 2);
```

Without this non-default constructor, a default constructor taking no parameters would have been automatically generator for you, so you could have made an object like this:

```
student_Example example;
```

Now you have defined a constructor that will no longer happen. You either need to add this to your class, or make sure you use the constructor taking parameters.

Comment: thank you doctorlove (great nickname btw :)) I wasnt aware that I must declare the constructor within the class, I thought that this was defined by the "::" in the constructor file (?). Any how I added the constructor but still get an error message in the main file saying :"no matching function for call to 'student_Example::student_Example()'

Comment: The `student_Example::student_Example(char nam, int marc1, int marc2);` declares the non-default constructor in the header, and the function with the matching signature in the cpp file defines it. Added an edit with details for your next problem

Answer (score 1):

[doctorlove](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42721160/3768496) fixes your issue, but is also good practice to have the methods in the `.cpp` file, like this:

**student_Example.h**

```
#ifndef STUDENT_EXAMPLE_H
#define STUDENT_EXAMPLE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class student_Example
{
    public:
        student_Example(char nam, int marc1, int marc2); //<-- as pointed out in the error
        char name;
        int mark1, mark2;

        int calc_media();

        void disp();
};
#endif
```

**student_Example.cpp**

```
#include "student_Example.h"

student_Example::student_Example(char nam, int marc1, int marc2) :
    name(nam),
    mark1(marc1),
    mark2(marc2) //assume maerc2 was a typo
{    
}

int student_Example::calc_media(){
    return (mark1+mark2/2);
}

void student_Example::disp(){
    std::cout<< " The student named: "<< name<< "\n has an average score equal to: " << calc_media()<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi i still get an error message saying:" no matching function for call to 'student_Example::student_Example()'. could you explain why this coding is good practice? what is the difference with what I have done? :)

Comment: I tested your code and found some problems. First: the problem `no matching function for call to 'student_Example::student_Example()'` is because you are trying to call the constructor without parameters. In the `main.cpp` where you have `student_Example student1;` change it to `student_Example student1(nam, marc1, marc2);`. I also noticed that the way you are calculating the average is not quite right, change from `return (mark1+mark2/2);` to `return ((mark1+mark2)/2);`.

Comment: It's a good practice because of how the compiler handles the header files. In short terms, the include of a `.h` file means the code in the header file will be copied to location of the include in compilation time, the more code you have in the `.h` the more time it will take to compile.